# Specify DNS/Domain Controller when authenticating against a different domain

Tags: active-directory, server-message-block, internal-dns, windows-authentication, net-use

Client has two domains residing on the same subnet/physical network. Essentially there's just a POP3 mail server (`OLDSERVER`) and one of the old DCs (`OLDDC`) on life support to keep `OLDSERVER` happy.  There is no trust established between the two forests; they're not aware of each other's existence.

I want to temporarily mount a mapped drive via `net use` to `OLDSERVER` from `NEWSERVER` so I can run a file sync job over the course of a few nights to get all the mail data off of the old server, but I'm getting trust relationship errors, regardless of how the domain is specified with the `/USER:` option.

I'm reasonably certain that if I changed the DNS server bindings on `NEWSERVER` or maybe added a forwarder for the old FQDN to the `OLDDC`, I could possibly get this to work, but I'd rather find a command line method of specifying which DC to query/authenticate against so that I can map a drive temporarily; thinking out loud, a hostfile entry for the required DNS entries for the old domain, resolving to the `OLDDC` required may be a potential solution too.

Another alternative may be just to install a temporary FTP server and avoid SMB/Windows-based authentication altogether (or just use a USB drive), but I'm more curious than anything right now to know if this is possible.

EDIT: HOSTS file method will likely not work as SRV records are not supported.  For non-SRV aware clients, you can specify a particular A record, but I would suspect that non-SRV aware clients would *not* include Windows Server 2008 R2; from an [MSDN blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/servergeeks/archive/2014/07/12/dns-records-that-are-required-for-proper-functionality-of-active-directory.aspx) on required DNS records for Active Directory:

> GC IP Address - `gc._msdcs.<DnsForestName>`
>
> Allows a non-SRV-aware client to locate any Global Catalog server in the forest by looking up >an A record. A name in this form is returned to the LDAP client through an LDAP referral. A >non-SRV-aware client looks up this name; an SRV-aware client looks up the appropriate SRV >resource record.
>
> Net Logon also registers a DNS CNAME (alias) record for use by Active Directory replication >The Locator does not use this record.

Comment: Why not authenticate with local user credentials to `OLDSERVER` and bypass the domain altogether?

Comment: @joeqwerty Yeah, that's what I ended up doing.